# Get group of index values for word count more than 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get index values along with that count of each word is more than 1 as list.

```
Ref="easy to get to know to easy of to"
```

With the `Ref` input I have this table say df1

```
 word   Count
 easy   2
  to    4
 get    1
 know   1
  of    1
```

And `df` is

```
Index   word
   0    easy
   1    to
   2    get
   3    to
   4    know
   5    to
   6    easy
   7    of
   8    to
```

So from these two table `df` and `df1` what I want is

```
Index          word   count
[0,6]          easy     2
[1,3,5,8]       to      4
[2]             get     1
[4]            know     1
[7]             of      1
```

It will be really great if someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### groupby + map

You can group by `word` in `df` and then map by `word` in `df1`:

```
s = df.groupby('word')['Index'].apply(list)
df1['Index'] = df1['word'].map(s)

print(df1)

   word  Count         Index
0  easy      2        [0, 6]
1    to      4  [1, 3, 5, 8]
2   get      1           [2]
3  know      1           [4]
4    of      1           [7]
```

#### defaultdict

Alternatively, from first principles, you can use `collections.defaultdict` to construct a dictionary of lists containing indices. Then feed into `pd.DataFrame`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

Ref = "easy to get to know to easy of to"

d = defaultdict(list)

for idx, word in enumerate(Ref.split()):
    d[word].append(idx)

df = pd.DataFrame({'word': list(d.keys()), 'Index': list(d.values())})
df['count'] = df['Index'].map(len)

print(df)

          Index  word  count
0        [0, 6]  easy      2
1  [1, 3, 5, 8]    to      4
2           [2]   get      1
3           [4]  know      1
4           [7]    of      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Given df, as

```
       word
Index      
0      easy
1        to
2       get
3        to
4      know
5        to
6      easy
7        of
8        to
```

First, use `reset_index` to move the dataframe index into a column named 'Index':

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Next using the following `groupby` with `agg`:

```
df.groupby('word')['Index'].agg([list,'count']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   word          list  count
0  easy        [0, 6]      2
1   get           [2]      1
2  know           [4]      1
3    of           [7]      1
4    to  [1, 3, 5, 8]      4
```

Comment: This is smart :)

Comment: @jpp Thanks!  I appreciate that.